# I need to make a void function loop back with out making it crash or skip

Tags: c++

how do I make my choices not cause a recursion when I any other button aside from a number?

I've resorted to a cheesey way of doing it by not vetting the specific choices and leaving it to the else statement.

can you guys give me an example to make it work?

At the last statement of the void function, where the else leads to back to function, it just skips the function all together and I don't know how to make it go back to the choices.

I've tried adding an if(!cin) to vet the process, but it just made it worse.

```
void forest() {
    cout << "               ,@@@@@@@,\n";
    cout << "       ,,,.   ,@@@@@@/@@,  .oo8888o.\n";
    cout << "    ,&%%&%&&%,@@@@@/@@@@@@,8888 8/8o" << endl;
    cout << "   ,%&%&&%&&%,@@@ @@@/@@@88 88888/88'\n";
    cout << "   %&&%&%&/%&&%@@ @@/ /@@@88888 88888'\n";
    cout << "   %&&%/ %&%%&&@@  V /@@' `88 8 `/88'\n";
    cout << "   `&%  ` /%&'    |.|          '|8'\n";
    cout << "       |o|        | |         | |\n";
    cout << "       |.|        | |         | |\n";
    cout << "      / ._ /_/__ /  , _/ __  /.   _/__/_\n";


    int forChoice = 0;
    int goFurther = 0;
    cout << "Choose the following paths\n";
    cout << "1. Go north.\n2. Go south.\n3. Go east.\nPress any to go to where the Goddess pointed.\n";
    cin >> forChoice;
    cout << endl;

    if (forChoice == 1) {
        cout << "I find the forrest to be denser, and I hear loud rustling noises in the dark.\n";
        cout << "I decide to turn back.\n";
        forest();
    } else if (forChoice == 2) {
        cout << "I appear to be heading towards a cliff.\n";
        cout << "The moon lights the whole landscape and the spectacular view of the terrain is something to behold.\n";
        cout << "There is nothing left to do for me, but to turn back.\n";
        forest();
    } else if (forChoice == 3) {
        cout << "I head east to see if there is anything to be found in that direction.\n";
        cout << "I hear wolves howling in the distance.\n";
        cout << "Do I continue, or turn back?\n1. Continue or press any other key to turn back\n";
        cin >> goFurther;
        if (goFurther == 1) {
            cout << "I hear a rustling noise as I venture on. A wolf lunges form behind me and bites my thigh.\n";
            cout << "I am now immobilized, and bleeding, as I see my vision fade away.\n";
            die();
        } else {
            cout << "I decided to turn back to evade uncertain dangers\n";
            forest();
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    int explore = 0;
    cout << "I have the option to explore the surrounding area. Do I explore or head straight to my task?\n";
    cout << "1. Explore OR Press any to go to task.\n";
    cin >> explore;
    if (explore == 1) {
        forest();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You indeed grew a nice forest :) To find out, try to better separate the different concerns i.e. drawing, showing options, getting input.

Comment: Could you provide the given input and output?

Comment: I used an if statement before like if(!cin or forChoice !=1 or forChoice !=3 etc...) , but when I enter the letter, g or any other character, the program does an infinite loop.

Comment: @NewToCoding to evade the infinite loop problem, you have to change the type of `forChoice` to string, as `int` variable can only hold numbers

Answer (score 0):

On the level of C++ knowledge you seem to have, it's pretty hard to solve this task, but I will try anyway.

Try to concentrate on the simplest possible game logic first and start with a minimalist game.

- I see (guess) that you intend to deal with these components:

  - Scenes (with a description)
  - Options (what to do where)
  - The player (who is in one scene at a given time)
- The player should be able to move between scenes
- Display a short description of the scene you are in (for example: `Forrest.`)
- Display scene-specific options, print them in a `for` loop (with key input added automatically)
- Imagine a way to get out of the game (maybe by typing `"x"`), add this to each option list
- Get user input (if you use a `std::string` variable to read into, compare with `"1"`, `"2"` etc.)

To manage the game, you should run a simple loop that displays the current scene and gets the user input. Before that, you have to build the game structure by using variables for scenes to connect them with options.

Here is an example how such a simplistic setup may look like hoping to make things a bit more clear. *Please note that I used `struct` instead of `class`, and started the code with `use namespace std;` both keeps the code small but is considered bad style for serious programs.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Scene;

struct Option
{
    Option(const string& t, Scene* s): text(t), scene(s) {}
    string text;
    Scene* scene;
};

struct Scene
{
    Scene(const string& t): text(t) {}
    string text;
    vector<Option> options;
};

struct Player
{
    Player(Scene* s): situation(s) {}
    Scene* situation;

    // the actual game loop
    void enjoy()
    {
        while (situation) {
            const vector<Option>& options = situation->options;
            cout << "you are here: " << situation->text << endl;
            for (size_t i=0; i<options.size(); ++i) {
                cout << i+1 << ": " << options[i].text << endl;
            }
            cout << "x: to exit game" << endl;
            string choice;
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == "x") {
                return;
            } else {
                int opt = atoi(choice.c_str());
                if ((0 < opt) && (opt <= int(options.size()))) {
                    situation = options[opt-1].scene;
                } else {
                    cout << "still ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    // create some scenes
    Scene forest("forest");
    Scene field("field");
    Scene hill("hill");

    // add options to scenes (and link scenes):
    forest.options.push_back(Option("Go to field", &field));
    forest.options.push_back(Option("Go to hill", &hill));
    field.options.push_back(Option("Go to forest", &forest));
    field.options.push_back(Option("Go to hill", &hill));
    hill.options.push_back(Option("Go to forest", &forest));

    // add player, placed in one scene
    Player player(&forest);

    // actually run the game
    player.enjoy();
    return 0;
}
```